# The servers are alive but the clients aren't! "No installed keys could decrypt the message", how to resolve this on consul?

Tags: consul, consul-health-check

Once I enabled `encrypt`, all my **consul cluster** failed. this is `sudo systemctl consul status`:

**memberlist: failed to receive: No installed keys could decrypt**

```
Nov 01 08:49:30 server-1 consul[593217]: 2021-11-01T08:49:30.031+0330 [ERROR] agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: failed to receive: No installed keys could decrypt the message from=10.10.10.7:37442
Nov 01 08:49:58 server-1 consul[593217]: 2021-11-01T08:49:58.992+0330 [ERROR] agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: failed to receive: No installed keys could decrypt the message from=10.10.10.4:41492
Nov 01 08:49:59 server-1 consul[593217]: 2021-11-01T08:49:59.882+0330 [ERROR] agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: failed to receive: No installed keys could decrypt the message from=10.10.10.12:35558
Nov 01 08:50:00 server-1 consul[593217]: 2021-11-01T08:50:00.042+0330 [ERROR] agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: failed to receive: No installed keys could decrypt the message from=10.10.10.7:37460
Nov 01 08:50:29 server-1 consul[593217]: 2021-11-01T08:50:29.004+0330 [ERROR] agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: failed to receive: No installed keys could decrypt the message from=10.10.10.4:41510
Nov 01 08:50:29 server-1 consul[593217]: 2021-11-01T08:50:29.895+0330 [ERROR] agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: failed to receive: No installed keys could decrypt the message from=10.10.10.12:35576
Nov 01 08:50:30 server-1 consul[593217]: 2021-11-01T08:50:30.056+0330 [ERROR] agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: failed to receive: No installed keys could decrypt the message from=10.10.10.7:37478
Nov 01 08:50:59 server-1 consul[593217]: 2021-11-01T08:50:59.018+0330 [ERROR] agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: failed to receive: No installed keys could decrypt the message from=10.10.10.4:41528
Nov 01 08:50:59 server-1 consul[593217]: 2021-11-01T08:50:59.909+0330 [ERROR] agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: failed to receive: No installed keys could decrypt the message from=10.10.10.12:35594
Nov 01 08:51:00 server-1 consul[593217]: 2021-11-01T08:51:00.067+0330 [ERROR] agent.server.memberlist.lan: memberlist: failed to receive: No installed keys could decrypt the message from=10.10.10.7:37496
```

The `ACL` and `TLS` are commented out, I even comment `encrypt` in all of my `clients`, but still received the above output.
How am I able to resolve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have exactly the same `encrypt` settings on both types of node: server and client. Or, you must have encryption disabled everywhere. You can consult the [official tutorial](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/gossip-encryption-secure#enable-gossip-encryption-existing-cluster) of step-by-step enabling encryption on the existing cluster.

**UPD:**
Some useful commands to use one key in all nodes (both client and server).

Get keys info from all nodes

```
consul keyring -list
```

Generate new key

```
consul keygen
```

Broadcast new key to all nodes

```
consul keyring -install=<<KEY>>
```

Switch to a new key

```
consul keyring -use=<<KEY>>
```

Comment: I actually already did that, but  when I `consul keyring -list-primary` I get different results. From server 2 -> `==> Gathering installed primary encryption keys...

WAN:
  9w9Q79tTnLcz7y8bAus64E54vdR0j7STRzPDWDxMs34= [1/1]

dc1 (LAN):
  nrbQkQigyUL0ME6lnJKZhZuDycwx56FjCeUOJgHGiFg= [1/1]
`. But from server 3 I get `==> Gathering installed primary encryption keys...

WAN:
  9w9Q79tTnLcz7y8bAus64E54vdR0j7STRzPDWDxMs34= [2/2]

dc1 (LAN):
  9w9Q79tTnLcz7y8bAus64E54vdR0j7STRzPDWDxMs34= [2/2]
`. I even tried manually removing `/consul/serf/local.keyring` file, but didn't work either.

Comment: I also did `consul keyring -remove` my previous token `9w9Q79tTnLcz7y8bAus64E54vdR0j7STRzPDWDxMs34=` but did not allowed `==> Removing gossip encryption key...
error: Unexpected response code: 500 (6 errors occurred:
        * WAN error: 2/2 nodes reported failure
        * server-1.dc1: Removing the primary key is not allowed
        * server-3.dc1: Removing the primary key is not allowed
        * dc1 (LAN) error: 2/2 nodes reported failure
        * server-1: Removing the primary key is not allowed
        * server-3: Removing the primary key is not allowed
` and docs didn't help.

Comment: You should use an equal encryption key for every DC. Try to set an equal key everywhere by using `consul keyring -use` command.

Comment: Thnaks, I changed the key on `/etc/consul.d/consul.hcl` and restarted the `consul.service` But now when I try `consul keyring -use=9w9Q79tTnLcz7y8bAus64E54vdR0j7STRzPDWDxMs34=` I get the following error `==> Changing primary gossip encryption key...
error: Unexpected response code: 500 (2 errors occurred:
        * dc1 (LAN) error: 1/1 nodes reported failure
        * server-2: Requested key is not in the keyring
`

Comment: Execute `consul keyring -install=9w9Q79tTnLcz7y8bAus64E54vdR0j7STRzPDWDxMs34=` to broadcast key to all nodes. Then try `-use`

Comment: I think, I should read more documentations :) I accept your answer as `solved`. please edit and complete it. Thank you for your time and knowledge.